# Xcode 6.0.1 Won't Start

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Hi I downloaded apple's release of Xcode 6 however when I open the application i get the error "The Application "Xcode" Cannot be opened -1712. Anyone know why or what is causing this. Also it might help to know when I downloaded apples previous Xcode 6 gm seed the same thing occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Preferences -> Security -> General tab. Check the box open app from anywhere. Then retry opening Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, just remember to check back to "Mac App Store and identified developers" once you run it otherwise you're opening your computer to run everything and unless you know very well what you are doing (and even in that case) that's a serious downgrade to your system's security.